# OpenMP Firstprivate clause

Tags: openmp

Does anyone know if the following can be an example of firstprivate in openmp?

```
rowstr[0] = 0;
for (j = 1; j < nrows+1; j++) {
    rowstr[j] = rowstr[j] + rowstr[j-1];
}
nza = rowstr[nrows] - 1;
```

firstprivate variable is `rowstr` and `j` is a private variable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually not, if you use the firstprivate clause you may have inconsistency in your output as some values would never be updated, clarifying:

Let's suppose it's an array of size 4 and you have 2 threads, one thread you get iterations 0 and 1 and the other 2 and 3 (in a perfect world). If you use the firstprivate clause the second thread will sum the position 2 of the array with was initially in the array in position 1, instead of summing it with the previous iteration as the sequential version would do.

Not just that, this particular loop have dependency issues and you should use something like a sum reduction in nza.